How in camunda subprocess dont create multpile user tasks?
I'm facing an issue in my application where a new user task is being created every time I access a subprocess. The behavior is causing multiple tasks to appear unnecessarily, as shown in the screenshots below: enter image description here enter image description here
What I want to achieve is to have the user task created only once and reused for subsequent subprocess accesses. How can I prevent the creation of a new user task each time a subprocess is accessed?
